# Unicode characters are not displayed when running android application in a device

Tags: android, unicode

I am using unicode characters in my android application. When I run the application in emulator it works fine but when I run it in real devices, the unicode characters are not displayed. I know the unicode font is missing in my real device, but what I wanna  know is that how to include the unicode font in my package so that it will be included when I install it wherever I want. I saw some samples of putting your font in the assets folder and changing the typeface of every component in the application. But, I need a simpler solution.

cheers!

Comment: THat is the solution.  Every component uses the default system font unless its overridden.  The user can change the default system fault, but normally its set to an appropriate font for their language.  If you want to override that everywhere, be prepared to write a lot of code/xml.

Comment: Add a font, change the typefaces.  Just like you said.  That is what to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "Unicode characters"? Does this mean you cannot see *any text at all*, not even the [Unicode character ʟᴀᴛɪɴ sᴍᴀʟʟ ʟᴇᴛᴛᴇʀ ᴀ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061/index.htm)?